# Shortest path curve through four points including three with double traverse.

Tags: graph-theory, calculus-of-variations, knot-theory

What may be the definition of the shortest smooth continuously differentiable plane curve through four given points including three given self-intersections among them?

Thanks for exploration, am new to graph theory; hope at least the question makes sense, so included a sketch of the $ 4+3=7$ points.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some path consisting of straight lines is the shortest. But it’s not “smooth”. You can make it smooth by adding little [fillets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fillet_(mechanics)) at the sharp corners. By making the fillets very small, you can get an arclength that’s arbitrarily close to the straight-line path.

If you want something even smoother, consider this example. Take the points $A=(-1,0)$, $B=(0,1)$, $C=(1,0)$. The shortest path from $A$ to $C$ obviously consists of two straight lines. But you could also draw a hyperbola passing through the three points, with it’s “peak” (point of maximum curvature) at $B$. By making the peak point sharper, you can get arbitrarily close to the straight line solution. In fact, in the limit, the hyperbola becomes a pair of straight lines.

Comment: At start and end of fillets there is second order discontinuity.

Comment: Yes. You can make smoother fillets, if you want. You didn’t say what you meant by “smooth”.

Comment: Given a piecewise linear curve $[0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ that's equal to $f_i(t)$ on $[a_i,b_i]$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, take a smooth [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) $\psi_1, \dots, \psi_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $\psi_i$ is $0$ outside $[a_i-\epsilon, b_i+\epsilon]$. Then the curve $\sum_{i=1}^n \psi_i(t) f_i(t)$ is smooth and will pass through all the same points for small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: So the problem is not posed properly?

Comment: @Narasimham There is a non-differentiable solution (connect points with line segments). No matter what smooth curve you have found so far you can always find a shorter one, so the space of smooth curves doesn't contain a solution

Comment: Think I agree. It is no different from a two point situation. Misha Levrov has said so in other words. If you care to put it  for an answer, shall accept it.